# how to make cygwin tar output proper unicode letters instead of shashed values?

Tags: unicode, cygwin, tar

I have a `*.tar.gz` file that have inside occasionally some names with non ascii letters.

for example when tar encounter a file containing word: `naïve` it outputs: `na\303\257ve`

Is there any swich, or tool to convert these slashed values to a proper letter ?

Answer (score 0):

> http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html
>
> By default GNU tar attempts to unquote each file or member name, replacing escape sequences according to the following table:  ...
>
> This default behavior is controlled by the following command line
>   option:
>
> ```
> --unquote
>     Enable unquoting input file or member names (default).
>
> --no-unquote
>     Disable unquoting input file or member names.
> ```

In other words, see if "--no-unquote" is an option for your version of Cygwin.

PS:
Which version of Cygwin tar *are* you using?

Comment: No it doesn't make any difference. I have the latest for now, that is: `1007.35.0.0`, maybe some regex trix or there is a way to make a program in c++ to convert these codes.